# NServicebus without any persistence?

Tags: nservicebus

A newbie question : If I am not using Sagas or pub/sub model, do I need any persistence layer with NServiceBus?

The default persistence is RavenDB, I was wondering if I just use NSB without RavenDB or any persistence layer?

Side note:
Currently I have to run RavenDBServer.exe before I can even play around with NserviceBus, so if I do start using NServiceBus, I don't want to have a dependency on another app running in production. This could be a issue with my install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus only uses persistence for storing subscriptions for pub/sub and for saga state. If you aren't using those then you don't need RavenDB or any other implementation. I believe the NServiceBus.Core binary by default comes bundled with RavenDB DLLs, but it won't be needed in production in your case.

Comment: That's almost entirely true. There is also the second-level retries feature, Bus.Defer, and scheduling that all make use of our durable time management which require some kind of persistence for reliability.

Comment: Thanks Udi, I completely overlooked those!

Comment: But all of those persistence stories can be configured to use SQL or other means via a pluggable architecture. Even storing as serialized XML on a filesystem would be technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could also use the NServiceBus.Lite profile which I believe uses in memory persistence.  This is a great way to go as you are developing and trying to learn NServiceBus.  However, I'm not sure you'd want to do so in production.  It would be a better practice to have some persistence either in a database or file system to ensure reliability of your application in the case of errors or application restarts.